# Change color of toast message in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

This is the toast I have created:

```
const toast = await this.toast.create({
        showCloseButton: true,
        message: 'Please Fill Data',
        duration: 30000,
        position: 'bottom',
        cssClass:'iontoast'
      });
      toast.present();
```

Styles which I applied to it:

```
iontoast{
    .toast-message{
        --background:white !important;
        --color:black !important;
    }
    .toast-container
    {
        --background:white !important;
        --color:black !important;
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
ion-toast{
 --background:white !important;
 --color:black !important;
}
```

Both of them didn't worked for me. How should I apply it to both `android` and `ios`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

1. color property can be passed as options, look below

```
await this.toastController.create({
            message: 'Hello World',
            color: 'danger',
            duration: 2000,
            position: 'top',
            showCloseButton: true,
            closeButtonText: 'Close'
        });
```

you can pass any other color as well like primary, secondary, success, etc which are provided in the theme/variable.scss file.

2. Using your custom css class
   you need to prepend ion-toast to your custom css class, look below

```
ion-toast.my_custom_class {
      // Css rules or using css custom properties
}
```

and just pass your custom class name to toast controller

Comment: Thanks for quick response but how do I set background of toast? What about customizing it our own way?

Comment: this will set both the background and text color. You can create a custom color with some name in theme/variable.scss file and use it as said above. Color given in theme color is taken as background and it's contrast is used for text color.

Answer (score 4):

to change the toast button color, the solution which worked for me was:

```javascript
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: 'your toast message text',
  duration: 3000,
  cssClass: 'toast-error',
  showCloseButton: true,
  closeButtonText: 'Undo'
});
```

and in my css file:

```css
page-my.page.scss.name {
        // my regular css code
}

.toast-error .button-inner {
    color: color($colors, danger);
}
```

if you want also to change the background color of your toast message, add the follow code in your scss file:

```css
.toast-container {
    background-color: #a5a0a0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: 'your toast message text',
  duration: 3000,
  cssClass: 'custom_class'
});
```

And in global.scss

```
.custom_class{
   color:my_color;
  }
```